# Tensorflow serving and client call failed

Tags: python-3.x, docker, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

Is anything goes wrong because i am getting connection failure while trying to make a client call with the help of (localhost:8517 or 10.110.110.13:8517)

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/serving# docker run -p 8517:8517 --mount type=bind,source=/root/serving/Ser_Model,target=/models/firstmodel -e MODEL_NAME=firstmodel -t tensorflow/serving
2018-12-18 22:42:54.202137: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:82] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: firstmodel model_base_path: /models/firstmodel
2018-12-18 22:42:54.203105: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:461] Adding/updating models.
2018-12-18 22:42:54.203162: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:558]  (Re-)adding model: firstmodel
2018-12-18 22:42:54.305763: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: firstmodel version: 1}
2018-12-18 22:42:54.305814: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: firstmodel version: 1}
2018-12-18 22:42:54.305856: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: firstmodel version: 1}
2018-12-18 22:42:54.305899: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/bundle_shim.cc:363] Attempting to load native SavedModelBundle in bundle-shim from: /models/firstmodel/1
2018-12-18 22:42:54.306021: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /models/firstmodel/1
2018-12-18 22:42:54.313227: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2018-12-18 22:42:54.314376: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-12-18 22:42:54.341301: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:162] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2018-12-18 22:42:54.354011: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:138] Running MainOp with key legacy_init_op on SavedModel bundle.
2018-12-18 22:42:54.354072: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:259] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 48045 microseconds.
2018-12-18 22:42:54.354116: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:83] No warmup data file found at /models/firstmodel/1/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
2018-12-18 22:42:54.354305: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:86] Successfully loaded servable version {name: firstmodel version: 1}
2018-12-18 22:42:54.356224: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:286] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
2018-12-18 22:42:54.356982: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:302] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
[evhttp_server.cc : 237] RAW: Entering the event loop ...
```

Trying to Get status of the model as follows:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8517/v1/models/firstmodel
```

But i got the error message `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Could you figure it out what was wrong in my serving command via docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8517 is the port your docker container expose. But you started your tf-server on port 8500 and 8501 in the container. If you want to make it work, change your docker cmd to `docker run -p 8501:8501 xxx`, and change request url to `localhost:8501/xxx/xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of port (8500 for GRPC and 8501 for RESTful API) matters are lot and link of [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857989/tensorflow-predict-grpc-not-working-but-restful-api-working-fine/53863597#53863597)

Serving for GRPC clients

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 --mount type=bind,source=/root/serving/Ser_Model,target=/models/firstmodel -e MODEL_NAME=firstmodel -t tensorflow/serving
```

Serving RESTful API clients

```
 docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/root/serving/Ser_Model,target=/models/firstmodel -e MODEL_NAME=firstmodel -t tensorflow/serving
```

And you can check the status of RESTful api client and calling as well,

```
curl http://localhost:8501/v1/models/firstmodel

curl -d '{"signature_name":"predict_output","instances":[2.0,9.27]}' -X POST http://10.110.110.13:8501/v1/models/firstmodel:predict
```