# Tensorflow predict grpc not working but RESTful API working fine

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, grpc, tensorflow-serving

When i am trying to execute below piece of client code i am getting error but succeeded when calling via RESTful API end point
`curl -d '{"signature_name":"predict_output","instances":[2.0,9.27]}' -X POST http://10.110.110.13:8501/v1/models/firstmodel:predict`

Could you please correct me in below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2_grpc
import numpy as np
import grpc
server = '10.110.110.13:8501'
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(server)
stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'firstmodel'
request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_output'
request.inputs['input_x'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto([12.0], shape=[1]))
result_future = stub.Predict(request,40.)
print(result_future.outputs['output_y'])
```

Got the below error message:

```
_Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "Trying to connect an http1.x server"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1545248014.367000000","description":"Error received from peer",
    "file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1083,"grpc_message":"Trying to connect an http1.x server","grpc_status":14}"
```

Below is the composed request information for your reference

```
model_spec {
  name: "firstmodel"
  signature_name: "predict_output"
}
inputs {
  key: "input_x"
  value {
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: 1
      }
    }
    float_val: 12.0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GRPC port and HTTP port are different. Since you are listening for your http service on 8501, you GRPC service must use another port. The default is 8500 but you could change it with the `--port=` argument when you start your tf-server.

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 --mounttype=bind,source=/root/serving/Ser_Model,target=/models/firstmodel -e MODEL_NAME=firstmodel -t tensorflow/serving
```

Comment: Thank you so much and save my days, Use line for gRPC <<docker run -p 8500:8500 --mount type=bind,source=/root/serving/Ser_Model,target=/models/firstmodel -e MODEL_NAME=firstmodel -t tensorflow/serving>> and use this line for RESTful API <<docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/root/serving/Ser_Model,target=/models/firstmodel -e MODEL_NAME=firstmodel -t tensorflow/serving>>                                                                And the final doubt is how to use our own ports? Do we need to do anything special?

Comment: You could add flag `--entrypoint bash` like this `docker run -p YOUR_PORT:YOUR_PORT --entrypoint bash OTHER_FLAGS -t tensorflow/serving -c "tensorflow_model_server --port=YOUR_PORT OTHER_FLAGS"`to overwrite the entrypoint in official docker image. Or you could build your own tensorflow-serving image with no entrypoint in it.